# run php function, display the response, and start another php function

Tags: php, real-time, response, flush

**Run php script, display the response, and start another php script and then display it**

I have two functions in php I would like to display the response of the first function in order to make loading less long

Exemple Pseudo-code

```
Function hello1()
{
   echo 'hello1';
   [...]
}
```

Show response and run another function

```
Function hello2()
{
   echo 'hello2'
   [...]
}
```

Comment: You mean sth. like that? http://www.php.net/manual/book.outcontrol.php

Comment: Have you tried any method yourself ? One way I can think of is using ajax. In your html/view add a ajax call to load the response and then based on the response you load the second part via another ajax call ?

Answer (score 0):

all php methods will be executed before rendering the html page. May you think about Javascript event handling or an method "injections" with Ajax request to a code behind file which is php based.

Regards,
Tobo